# Inequality for dimensions of eigenspaces of direct sum decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I want to proof that for an endomorphism $f$ over vector space $V$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and
$V = U \oplus V/U$ with $f(U) \subseteq U$ the following holds:
$$
\dim E(f,\lambda) \leq \dim E(f_U,\lambda) + \dim E(f_{V/U}, \lambda)
$$
I managed to proof that the inequality holds for the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ via splitting the characteristic polynomial of $f$. However I can't find a way to connect that to the geometric multiplicity. Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

Since $E(f_U,\lambda)$ is a subspace of $E(f,\lambda)$, we can find another subspace $W$ of $E(f,\lambda)$ such that $E(f,\lambda) = E(f_U,\lambda) \oplus W$. Thus $\dim E(f,\lambda) = \dim E(f_U,\lambda) + \dim W$ and $W$ can be realized as a subspace of $E(f_{V/U},\lambda)$ via the injective map $w \mapsto w+U$ for $w \in W$.